# MySQL - count rows if column value contains something

Tags: mysql

today I hit a stag when I realize that I need to count tags in database. I have table with tags column like

```
tags_column
tag1
tag1,tag2

tag1,somethingElse1
somethingElse1, somethingElse2
tag2
tag3,tag1

tag2
```

And I need to count how many rows contains e.g. tag1, tag2 and tag3 and how many rows ar without these tags. So I need something like

```
$qry = "SELECT COUNT(tags_Column) AS `tag1Count` WHERE `tags_Column` CONTAINS 'tag1', 
        (SELECT COUNT(tags_Column) FROM `TableContainsTags`) AS `tag2Count` WHERE `tags_Column` CONTAINS 'tag2',
        (SELECT COUNT(tags_Column) FROM `TableContainsTags`) AS `tag3Count` WHERE `tags_Column` CONTAINS 'tag3',
        (SELECT COUNT(tags_Column) FROM `TableContainsTags`) AS `notagCount` WHERE `tags_Column` DOESN'T_CONTAINS 'tag1' OR 'tag2' OR 'tag3'
        FROM `TableContainsTags`";
```

Do you have any idea, please?

Comment: Restructure your table to keep each tag in a separate row with an id where it belongs to.

Comment: Your database structure is wrong, restructure it to make it proper. You should have a tags table and a tagrelation table.

Comment: Or you could just query for the whole column and do the counting in PHP.

Comment: RST, your answer was the best for me, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT sum( case when `tags_Column` CONTAINS 'tag2' then 1 else 0 end ) as tag2,
       sum( case when `tags_Column` CONTAINS 'tag3' then 1 else 0 end ) as tag3,
       .....
       sum( case when `tags_Column` CONTAINS 'tag256' then 1 else 0 end ) as tag256,
       sum( case when `tags_Column` CONTAINS `tag2` OR 
                      `tags_Column` CONTAINS 'tag3`
            then 0 else 1 end ) as doesnt_contains_tags_2_3
FROM `TableContainsTags`
```